# How to make <g> svg-group within svg container draggable

Tags: jquery, user-interface, svg, draggable

I have a problem with making an svg-group  draggable within a svg.

Here is my problem isolated:

https://jsfiddle.net/mtj2jb9f/

HTML:

```
<svg id="body" width="300" height="20px">
  <g id="entry" x="0" style="width: 100px;">
    <rect class="entry-body" height="20" width="100" x="0" y="0"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

JS:

```
$("#entry").draggable();
```

Did I miss something? I can drag elements within the group, but not the group within the svg-container.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a background rect to the group to catch any areas that would otherwise be unrendered.

Note that g elements don't have x, y, width or height attributes or properties, they are always simply the size of their contents.

```js
$("#entry").draggable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<svg id="body" class="ui-widget-content" width="300" height="200px">
  <g id="entry">
    <rect width="100" height="200" visibility="hidden" pointer-events="all"/>
    <rect class="entry-body" height="20" width="100" x="0" y="0"></rect>
    <rect class="entry-body" height="20" width="100" x="0" y="50"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ah ok, so <g> is an abstract element? My idea was to move the group within the svg and to get the position of it for other calculations. But I will try another attempt. Thank you.

Comment: <g> is just a container